# Unable to activate Process Builder on EmailMessage Obj - unable to obtain exclusive access

Tags: workflow, process-builder, administration, concurrency

I am unable to activate a process builder and get the below error always. This is not a record that I am trying to update , it is a process builder.

I checked whether there is any flow pending in Setup->flow->Paused and Waiting Interviews.

[image]